# UISplitViewController's detail view suddently stopped being pushed up when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, ios5, keyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

Exactly what the title says. The problem is that at first it was behaving correctly, then I did something with rotation/orientation, and it started to behave this way:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4rcB8lzcpU

Now I restored the rotation thing and it still misbehaves. Question is: why?

Comment: You have to put your code and not a video link for how it acts!Put some code to understnad what have you done.

Comment: Up until now it behaved correctly. Then I changed the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation methods to only allow for landscape, and it started to misbehave. Restored them to allow all orientations, and it kept misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

You have to resize your `DetailViewController scrollview`, when keyboard appears. So that it will show you the `textField` appears to you. You have to add your resize code in `textFieldBeginEditing:` method and have to resize for old behaviour in `textFieldEndEditing:` method.

Comment: Here's what baffles me: if I make a new application using the Master-Detail template, make the detail view a UITableViewController, and I put a text field so that it certainly gets hidden by the keyboard, when the keyboard appears the tableview gets correctly managed by the system to move the text field above the keyboard.